# SWRevealViewController - How to retain the front view when switching to another one

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

If I have one rear view and two front view say 1 and 2, if I go to front view 1, and then switch to front view 2, is the view 1 gone from memory?

What if I have downloaded some data stored in a NSArray defined in front view 1 and then I go to 2, but I still want the data in 1 when I switch back to it?
Do I have to download it again when switching back to 1?
What's the best practice to do this?

I think my question is clear so I didn't paste my code.

Hope you can help me with it!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I leveraged NSCache to do this, so even though the view 1 was popped out of the stack, when I came back to create another one, I can load the old data from cache and do further update operations.